# Displaying generated jpg map on Google App Engine

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine, google-maps

I have an image created from the Google Maps API static map library and I'd like to make this visible on the screen.

How's the best way to do this? My map is being generated as follows:

```
map = urlfetch.fetch(url).content
```

Which should correspond to an image. My question is how best to place this image on the Django framework and GAE?

Thanks,

Comment: Also make user you are writing the response headers properly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you've generated a url that denotes a static map, which I think is the only way to do it, then you'll just want to use it as the src attribute of an img tag.

```
<img alt="My Map" src="{{url}}" />
```

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps